# Elastic4s client bulk operation error

Tags: scala, elastic4s

I am trying to use scala elstic4s client to index new documents into my elasticsearch cluster but I am having a compilation problem with the types. Following the documentation and the examples found in the web, the syntax looks like:

Client instantiation:

```
val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", Configuration.elasticsearchClusterName).build()    
val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://" + Configuration.elasticsearchUri)
val client = ElasticClient.remote(settings, uri)
```

I am trying to write it like:

```
def writeToElasticsearch(bulkList: List[EventMessage]) {
   val ops = for (message <- bulkList) yield index into indexDcp ttl 7.days.toMillis doc StringDocumentSource(message.toJSon()) 
   client.execute(bulk(ops: _*)).await
 }
```

I am getting a compilation error in the bulk operation saying:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch; found : List[com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDefinition] required: 
 Seq[Int]
```

Can anyone tell me how I can convert the types to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: What is the type of your "ops"? can you annotate it with List[com.sksamuel.elastic4s.IndexDefinition]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting errors, possibly something in the bits you've missed out of your code samples, but this version of your code compiles fine for me.

```
object Test extends App {

  val client = ElasticClient.local
  val indexDcp = "myindex/mytype"

  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import ElasticDsl._

  def writeToElasticsearch(bulkList: List[EventMessage]) {
    val ops = for (message <- bulkList) yield { index into indexDcp ttl 7.days.toMillis doc StringDocumentSource(message.toJSon()) }
    client.execute(bulk(ops: _*)).await
  }

  trait EventMessage {
    def toJSon(): String
  }
}
```